# When finding the force of a falling raindrop, how to account for not knowing the collision time?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, energy-conservation

So my question is to find the force of impact on the ground of a raindrop of mass $m$ that falls at velocity $v$ right as it hits the ground. So what I did was find the momentum of the object, which is $mv$, then divided by time $t$ to get the force. However, this is where I'm stuck, because it seems like $t$ is very small and unknown.

Comment: You are right about $t$ being small. The real difficulty however will arise from the fact that the drop is not solid and will deform dramatically. I have no idea how to deal with this.

Comment: @rv7 I'm removing your comment; please keep in mind that comments are not to be used for answering the question.

Comment: @Jasper hey i think for this we can use equations of perfectly in elastic collision .

Comment: The stupid answer is to take characteristic size of the rain droplet (1 mm) and divide it by velocity.

Comment: I don't think that the question was about finding the force from one single raindrop. It may be asking for the average force produced by many raindrops, given a specific rate of rainfall. Possibly an analogy with the force or pressure exerted by a gas on the wall of the container. Can you post the actual text of the problem?

Comment: I think that what @DavidSaykin suggests may not be stupid, if you agree it's a good approximation to take the waterdrop as spherical, then from $\rho V=m$ and the known mass density $\rho$ of water you can find the diameter of the rain droplet. (so you don't have to plug in $1mm$ by hand and hence account for varying sizes of droplets)

Answer (score 0):

You are right to suspect you can't find the force knowing only $m$ and $v$. In fact, dimensionally there is no force you can cook up out of them, so it's clear we are going to need to introduce some extra physics. That is, not every sphere of mass $m$ and speed $v$ hitting a wall experiences the same force. The difference between different spheres is the material they are made of so we're looking for a material property.

The simplest model I can think of to give at least *an* answer is this: assume we know also the density $\rho$ of the water and that as the raindrop lands it completely falls apart into some sort of puddle of negligible height. Then we can say the floor has done work on the raindrop to bring it to rest equal to:

$W_{floor} = Fr = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 $

We can use the relation $m = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$ to get rid of one of $r,m,\rho$. It's much easier to leave in terms of $m,r$ only but I suppose an engineer might prefer $m,\rho$ so:

$F = \frac{m}{2r}v^2 = (\frac{\pi}{6}\rho m^2)^{1/3}v^2$

(A more complicated model may want to take account of the fact that some work also needs to go into overcoming any cohesive energy the raindrop has, the fact the force isn't uniform so the peak force will be higher than this, and maybe some fluid mechanics effects I haven't thought of.)

Comment: I probably should have worded my problem better. This problem was actually about finding the force of a rainstorm on a spherical dog of mass $M >> m$ where the raindrops are absorbed by the dog's fur. The raindrops are assumed to have negligible volume. I was stuck with how to find the force of a single raindrop onto the dog and it's an introductory physics course, so I don't think we'll be looking at the material properties.